# wget can't find item online

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm currently making an ELK stack, but when I follow [these steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html) I get returned a 404 error. I can manually download the file if I enter the link into any browser, and even read the files in a GUI, but not in command prompt. It appears to fail after sending an HTTP request. Specifically, I am running the command:

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.2.2.tar.gz
```

Adding `sudo` in front doesn't change anything. If nothing else, would I just have to copy each folder (lib, var, etc.) manually?

**The Result of a quick debug:**

```
sudo wget --debug -S https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.2.tar.gz
Setting --server-response (serverresponse) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.17.1 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/login/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2018-02-26 12:42:40--  https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.2.tar.gz
Resolving artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)... 23.23.109.100, 184.73.156.41, 23.21.67.46, ...
Caching artifacts.elastic.co => 23.23.109.100 184.73.156.41 23.21.67.46 54.225.188.6 184.73.245.233 54.235.82.130 184.72.218.26 184.72.242.47 2406:da00:ff00::b849:f5e9 2406:da00:ff00::1715:432e 2406:da00:ff00::b848:da1a 2406:da00:ff00::ae81:1d9 2406:da00:ff00::36e1:bc06 2406:da00:ff00::1717:6d64 2406:da00:ff00::b849:9c29 2406:da00:ff00::b848:f22f
Connecting to artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)|23.23.109.100|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00005573f67f3fe0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x00005573f67f4560
certificate:
  subject: CN=*.elastic.co,O=Elasticsearch\\, Inc.,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
  issuer:  CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host artifacts.elastic.co

**---request begin---**
GET /downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.2.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.17.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: artifacts.elastic.co
Connection: Keep-Alive

**---request end---**
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
**---response begin---**
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 20:42:43 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
x-amz-id-2: amJi77MSQhFIYjeVp/GRn+Uo3pk/whLWxkRzu33+1evI7pdgK2V33fFRgt+xJDfOxy8HHDVwONY=
x-amz-request-id: C09CB1B31B2B1951
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive

**---response end---**

  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Content-Type: application/xml
  Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 20:42:43 GMT
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  x-amz-id-2: amJi77MSQhFIYjeVp/GRn+Uo3pk/whLWxkRzu33+1evI7pdgK2V33fFRgt+xJDfOxy8HHDVwONY=
  x-amz-request-id: C09CB1B31B2B1951
  Content-Length: 321
  Connection: keep-alive
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 321 bytes of body: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.2.tar.gz</Key><RequestId>C09CB1B31B2B1951</RequestId><HostId>amJi77MSQhFIYjeVp/GRn+Uo3pk/whLWxkRzu33+1evI7pdgK2V33fFRgt+xJDfOxy8HHDVwONY=</HostId></Error>] done.
2018-02-26 12:42:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Saving HSTS entries to /home/login/.wget-hsts
```

Comment: I get no errors with your `wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.2.2.tar.gz`; just a downloaded tarball.  (ie. your networking? network policy? .. or just you tried @ a bad time)

Comment: Oh yea, also running this in VMWare workstation. I've been going at it for at least an hour. If others are able to run it then it's something on my end, not sure what...

Comment: Works fine for me. Add the output of `wget --debug -S https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.2.2.tar.gz` to the question, please.

Comment: *output has been added*

Comment: are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Close voters crafting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your debug output you've made a typo. Considering the output:

```
**---request begin---**
GET /downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.2.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.17.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: artifacts.elastic.co
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Clearly instead of 6.6.2 you meant 6.2.2

Source:

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch